# overload given in MSDN not used during build

Tags: c#, msbuild

I’m trying to create an instance with C# reflection, but the intellisense and MSDN docs don’t seem to agree with msbuild about the available overloads of Activator.CreateInstance.

I have `System.Activator.CreateInstance(sting.empty, "typeName");` in my code with no complaints from intellisense and navigating to the definition gives me:

`static ObjectHandle CreateInstance(string assemblyName, string typeName);`

It's also listed on MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d133hta4(v=vs.110).aspx

However, when building, I get these two errors as if that overload doesn’t exist:

```
error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Type' 

error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'string' to 'object'
```

Is there some reason I wouldn’t be hitting that overload?

Comment: Have you checked that the overload exists for the version of the framework you're compiling against?

Comment: Trying to find that now, and it looks like VS may indeed be using a different version than msbuild. But, the MSDN pages seem to have the same overload available in every version